# Initialising Enum variables in constructor

Tags: java, enums

My enum looks like this :

```
public enum SignMethod {    

    MICROSOFT("Microsoft"),XML("Xml"),HDR("Hdr"),JAVA1("Java1");

    private final String name;
    private ArrayList<Server> servers = new ArrayList<>();
    private HashSet<String> fileTypes = new HashSet<>();

    public static void main(String... args) {
        System.out.println(MICROSOFT.getName()+" "+MICROSOFT.getServers()+ " " + MICROSOFT.getFileTypes());
        System.out.println(ServerAndSignMethodInitialiser.getServers(SignMethod.MICROSOFT));
        System.out.println(SignDataInitialiser.getFileTypesList(SignMethod.MICROSOFT));
    }

    private SignMethod(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        this.servers = ServerAndSignMethodInitialiser.getServers(this);
        System.out.println(servers);
        this.fileTypes = SignDataInitialiser.getFileTypesList(this);
        System.out.println(fileTypes);
    }
}
```

I am trying to initialise servers variable through a static initialiser class which has a Map that maps from SignMethod enum to ArrayList of servers. But when I am printing the servers right after initialisation in constructor, its printing null. Is there some problem in passing "this" in constructor to other method.

```
public static ArrayList<Server> getServers(SignMethod signMethod) {
    System.out.println(signMethod);
    return signmethodToServerMap.get(signMethod);        
}
```

When I am prinitng signMethod in getServers method its printing alright as "MICROSOFT" etc.

Comment: An enum having a main method is a strange thing indeed...

Comment: Where is it printing null actually?

Comment: how you fill `signmethodToServerMap`?

Comment: 1) what is signmethodToServerMap 2) this code won't compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Guess it's some kind of egg and chicken problem.

- The constructor for each enum value requires a call of the `getServers(SignMethod)` method.
- The `getServers(SignMethod)` method looks up in a `Map`.
- This `Map` has enum values as key. Thus, it *cannot* be filled before the enum value's constructor finished.

At the moment, I can think of three options to resolve the problem:

1. Keep the enum simple and don't try to store additional information in it. Then you can rely solely on the `signmethodToServerMap` to store your servers.
2. Instead of statically initializing a map, just store the `Server` list right in the enum.
3. Make the `Map` independent from the enum. So for example, map from `String` to `Server` and say

   ```
   this.servers = ServerAndSignMethodInitialiser.getServers(this.name);
   ```